# Where does AdBlock Plus store it's settings

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I have recently installed Ubuntu (14.04) on new partition. I still have the broken version of Ubuntu on the old partition and I want to copy some settings from it. Now I trying to find location of AdBlock plus settings and custom filters, because I use it only of few webs with excessive advertising. I have googled a lot with no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately the settings are stored in Chrome's own, encrypted storage. The files do exist on disk but finding a way to access them has given me a migraine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use adblock on chrome, but i know that some chrome configurations can be found under:

```
/home/<user>/.config/google-chrome
```

May you should take a look in the Default/Extensions folder.

Good luck!

Comment: I have searched that folder before I have posted the question. There is many files related to AdBlock, but I could not find any configuration/settings files.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that in Firefox custom hiding rules and custom blocking rules saved in a file called patterns.ini. Just installed AdBlock+ for Chrome, but could not find a pattern.ini file or any other file where custom rules have been saved. May you just copy the whole content of the adblock extension folder to your new machine, and see what happens, or you check the adblockplus.org forum. Probably the best way to get some informations.

Answer (score 0):

This comes a year late, but... here goes:
your ADP config file for Mozilla 42.0 on Trusty 14.04.x, as customized by the user, is located at:

```
 ~/.mozilla/firefox/id2jbmsn.default-ddddddddddddd/adblockplus/patterns.ini
```

where, on my box, `ddddddddddddd` stands for a 13 digit long numeral.

HTH, however late.